# How to deal with an elaborate question with interesting comments, when the OP later realizes that his problem lies elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm sure this has been tackled before but I couldn't find it.

In several low traffic tags that I follow (vim, glsl) I continuously come across questions where the OP elaborately describes a problem, only to later realize that the bug he was experiencing had nothing to do with all of that.

The question then lies abandoned and keeps popping up in various unanswered question lists...

How should these situations be tackled?

- the user cannot provide his solution as a proper answer because it would be something along the lines of "never mind, it was just me being stupid"
- on the other hand deleting the question altogether might be a bit extreme, given that comments to the question might contain interesting debugging insights for similar situations

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the question is not answerable and cluttering up the lists, it should be closed.

If it can be saved, it should be edited into a valid question.

If you can't do any of that, you can flag it for moderator attention.